# VMWare on Windows - Disabling Internet for CentOS7 VM without disabling network access

Tags: network-programming, centos7

I need two things:

1. Disabled Internet access on my VM.
2. Enabled local network access from my VM.

I'm currently trying to replicate a bug on my CentOS7 VM which requires that I have no direct internet access, only able to connect to the web through a proxy on my local network. I've taken two paths to this so far:

1. Disable the Internet on my Windows machine. **Why this didn't work:** My VM just...froze until the internet was turned back on. Currently considering looking into the possibility of a daemon and disabling it.
2. Disable Internet access only on my VM. **This hasn't worked yet.** It's the path I'm taking right now, but everything I've tried has done the same as the above: frozen my VM, only this time in order to get it back I need to shut it down completely and restart it. Given that I have to mount drives on it to do what I need to do, it's understandable that this is a less than ideal approach. Below are images of my NAT settings and the in-VM Network UI.

   [image: Current NAT Settings]
   [image: Network Adapter 1]
   [image: Network Adapter 2]

I've also gone in and turned on Airplane Mode, disabled the IPv4 and IPv6 manually, and went through all the network settings to see what there was. A Google search turned up nothing except an OSX-specific workaround which I couldn't replicate on my system.

Does anybody have any suggestions?

EDIT:

The above still applies, but I'm trying to take another route to #2. What I'd like to do is shut down all traffic to my VM except from the proxy and network. However, my network is accessible only through my host machine, so I don't want to shut my host machine out entirely, just internet coming from it. Any thoughts?

Comment: Sorry for the edit spam, but apparently it thought the images were code and wouldn't let me submit. Really hecking weird, bug reported to the staff.

Answer (score 0):

You could achieve the desired effect by disabling the nameserver configuration.
Just empty the `/etc/resolv.conf` file (of course after making a backup for later).